Azure arm64 VM sku with nested virtualization
I am what sku I should use that is based on arm64 + support nested virtualization as needed by Install-WindowsFeature "Hyper-V"
Install-WindowsFeature : A prerequisite check for the Hyper-V feature failed. azure-arm: 1. Hyper-V cannot be installed: The processor does not have required virtualization capabilities.

I have tried Standard_D2ps_v5 but it doesn't support nested virtualization.

You can use the Dv3 and Ev3 series in Azure that supports nested virtualization; Check the link https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/introducing-the-new-dv3-and-ev3-vm-sizes/. and https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/blog/itopstalkblog/how-to-setup-nested-virtualization-for-azure-vmvhd/1115338

I have check the ARM64 VM architecture, seems no size support Nested Virtualization which have the suffix of pdf, pls, or plds, etc
D2pds_v5 | Ampere Altra [Arm64] | Nested Virtualization: Not supported
D2pds_v6 | Azure Cobalt 100 [Arm64] | Nested Virtualization: Not supported
D2pls_v5 | Ampere Altra [Arm64] | Nested Virtualization: Not supported
D2pls_v6 | Azure Cobalt 100 [Arm64] | Nested Virtualization: Not supported
D2ps_v5 | Ampere Altra [Arm64] | Nested Virtualization: Not supported
D2ps_v6 | Azure Cobalt 100 [Arm64] | Nested Virtualization: Not supported
D2plds_v5 | Ampere Altra [Arm64] | Nested Virtualization: Not supported
D2plds_v6 | Azure Cobalt 100 [Arm64] | Nested Virtualization: Not supported

You can check details from this links

Further more, someone also confirm it, links



Azure arm64 VM sku with nested virtualization

The error you encountered above is due to the selected SKU: Standard_D2ps_v5, not supporting nested virtualization. You can use Dv3 and Ev3 series Windows Server VMs.Check nested virtualization-supported SKU's here.
I created a Windows VM with the SKU: Standard_E4s_v3 with Security Type: Standard.

Note: Nested Virtualization supports Security type: Stanadard


After creating the VM, Hyper-V was installed on the VM
 Install-WindowsFeature -Name Hyper-V -IncludeManagementTools

Output:

After restarting the VM, Hyper-V was installed on the VM.

Referecne:
How to Setup Nested Virtualization for Azure VM/VHD

I wanted arm64 VM, x64

Do you need arm64 or x64?

arm64 + TrustedLaunch + nested virtualization support, I don't know if there is one

Nested Virtualization support only Standard , chekc the MS doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1340315/hyper-v-cannot-be-installed-because-virtualization for more details

Hi @Node.JS,I hope this helps to resolve your problem. If you still need any help, let me know
